# Ambari Deployment Problems on VMs

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop2, ambari

I am working towards setting up a production Hadoop/Spark cluster in our enterprise, but am doing some testing first. Just to get some of the semantics out there:

Production OS: RHEL 7
CPU: 8-core
RAM: 64gb
Number of nodes: 12
Type: VMs

These production nodes are all VMs and have been given 1tb of data space which is a mount at /data/. Each of the system directories are given their own file system as well, such as /var/ has it's own file system, /usr/ and / have their own and are limited on size/space. Therefore, I am working on determining how much each of those file systems need in order to do a full stack install. I'll get back to that later.

For now, I am testing this on a DEV box, I have one box setup as the management node and have another box as the deployment node. My goal here is to tests a fully deployment to a single node to identify issues we might have before deploying to production. The only difference between the DEV nodes and the PROD nodes is that the DEV nodes are RHEL 6 and the data directory is /hadoopdata01/ and the DEV boxes are 4 core and 16gb of RAM. Again, the is only for testing, so I don't need it to actually function, I'm just trying to get through the install and deployment.

I can get ambari-server setup and working just fine on the management node. I have all the passwordless SSH setup between the two nodes, Java on both machines is OpenJDK 1.8 and the repo has been setup on both boxes. I have disabled SELINUX and disabled IPTABLES too, just to be safe

From there, I register the node, which works fine, and go through all the steps then click the deploy button. It seems to freeze at 4% and after 30 minutes (1800 seconds) on the Activity Analyzer Install and it times out with the following:

```
stderr: 
Python script has been killed due to timeout after waiting 1800 secs
 stdout:
2017-08-28 17:11:02,665 - Stack Feature Version Info: stack_version=2.6, version=None, current_cluster_version=None -> 2.6
2017-08-28 17:11:02,666 - Using hadoop conf dir: /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf
User Group mapping (user_group) is missing in the hostLevelParams
2017-08-28 17:11:02,667 - Group['hadoop'] {}
2017-08-28 17:11:02,669 - Group['users'] {}
2017-08-28 17:11:02,669 - User['zookeeper'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop']}
2017-08-28 17:11:02,671 - Adding user User['zookeeper']
2017-08-28 17:11:05,724 - User['ams'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop']}
2017-08-28 17:11:05,726 - Adding user User['ams']
2017-08-28 17:11:05,817 - User['ambari-qa'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['users']}
2017-08-28 17:11:05,819 - Adding user User['ambari-qa']
2017-08-28 17:11:05,915 - User['hdfs'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop']}
2017-08-28 17:11:05,916 - Adding user User['hdfs']
2017-08-28 17:11:06,049 - File['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh'] {'content': StaticFile('changeToSecureUid.sh'), 'mode': 0555}
2017-08-28 17:11:06,051 - Execute['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh ambari-qa /tmp/hadoop-ambari-qa,/tmp/hsperfdata_ambari-qa,/home/ambari-qa,/tmp/ambari-qa,/tmp/sqoop-ambari-qa'] {'not_if': '(test $(id -u ambari-qa) -gt 1000) || (false)'}
2017-08-28 17:11:06,056 - Skipping Execute['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh ambari-qa /tmp/hadoop-ambari-qa,/tmp/hsperfdata_ambari-qa,/home/ambari-qa,/tmp/ambari-qa,/tmp/sqoop-ambari-qa'] due to not_if
2017-08-28 17:11:06,057 - Group['hdfs'] {}
2017-08-28 17:11:06,057 - Adding group Group['hdfs']
2017-08-28 17:33:22,647 - User['hdfs'] {'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop', 'hdfs']}

Command failed after 1 tries
```

One other thing - I asked my VM guy to just expand the /usr/ file system, but he saw that the install takes place on /usr/hdp/ and decided to create me a whole new file system mounted as /usr/hdp/ with the 4gb of space I requested.... Is this what is causing my issues? Does Ambari want to create that space and therefore is giving me issues? After the error, I check the /usr/hdp directory and there are not files in it....

I have been scouring the net, but this is new to me... I know there should be some information in the logs, but I'm not sure which log to look at and if I should be looking at the logs on the management server or on the node I am trying to deploy to....

I have a few questions, but ultimately just want to test deployment of a basic Spark and Hadoop setup on a single node before I deploy to my production cluster. Here are a couple questions:

1. Can I even deploy a single node cluster this way, maybe that is my issue....
2. What logs or where should I be looking for further clues....I can post them, just not sure what is needed.
3. Again, I just want a basic Hadoop/Spark cluster - are there any pre-requirements I need to account for that Ambari doesn't do?

Comment: So, I have been playing around with this a bit more, seems to be hanging on creating users and groups - my VMs are part of an enterprise and use LDAP for authentication to AD. I know, in this case, I have had to issue commands such as "groupadd -r" in the past since a normal "gorupadd" on an LDAP autheticated box takes a long time to execute. Could this be my problem? Again, it seems to be timing out at that 1800s mark. I tried extending this to 3600s, but it results in the same thing, it just takes longer. Any ideas on how ambari is trying to create its users? Could this be the issue?

Comment: yes, sounds like misconfigured LDAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bring a close to this, since we are not using LDAP/AD at this time, but our Linux environment does leverage LDAP, the issue was that Amabri was attempting to create local users. Before it could do so, it was searching through LDAP to assure that the users did not already exist. These search took a long time (5-10 per user) given the size of our LDAP/AD forests (not sure why it was taking so long, but it was). After around 2-3 service accounts, the whole deployment script on the back-end would time out, since there is an overall timer on the deployment with Ambari.

My solution was to create these users and groups ahead of time. Then, in Ambari during the Cluster creation, in Advanced setting, tell Amabri to ignore creation of user groups/accounts. After that it was smooth sailing. I suppose if I was using AD/LDAP integration, we'd have to create these ahead of time in those system anyway. The only way I could have avoided this was if I wasn't using LDAP/AD at all.... Anyhow, I wanted to post this solution that worked for us, we are up and running after manually creating the local users and groups.